# Eliminate white space top between wordpress articles

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qngvw.png

How do i get rid of that top margin of every articles in my wp ? (see image above) like unordered rows. I need for that article to not align top with the biggest article of the last row, but for that who is above him.

I have searched everywhere and nothing works till now.

Answer (score 1):

Because this isn't how `div`-based html/css works, you're going to have to either use [CSS3 columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts), or JavaScript.

You haven't shared any markup, but using CSS3 Columns will likely require you to restructure the way posts are currently being output. Also note that this will order posts top-to-bottom per row, rather than left-to-right.

If you need posts ordered in rows from left to right, you'll want to use a JavaScript plugin, such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: i tought about top to bottom, but it doesn't fit for my theme because there are many posts on a single page..

Comment: Then you'll need to use javascript, as mentioned.

Comment: that plugin is doing exactly the same thing .. from top to bottom.

Comment: No, it's not. But that's really beside the point. The point is that you're going to need to use JS. How you do it is up to you, and beyond the scope of this question, or answer.